# using groupby on DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Ouis AL-Hetar\Documents\TestEmployeeTable1.csv")
sal= df.groupby("Department").sum("Salary").reset_index()
sal.columns=["Dapartment","Sum_of_salary"]

print(sal)
```

when i treid run this code ir raise an Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tzpk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQn8S.png)

i have tried print head() for checking if there is any errors in the names of columns :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dCZ.png)
but i note any error

i hope someone who knows what's the problem help me ,
sorry for my discusting English

Comment: need `df.head().to_dict()`. need copyalbe text for answer

Comment: Please post the error as text

Answer (score 1):

The default separator of CSV file is `,`. In your case, it seems the separator is a semicolon and not a comma so you need to set `sep=";"` as parameter of `pd.read_csv` to correctly read your file:

```
#                                        HERE --v
df = pd.read_csv("TestEmployeeTable1.csv", sep=";")
```

However, you have to modify the rest of your code:

```
sal = df.groupby("Department", as_index=False)["Salary"].sum()
sal.columns = ["Department", "Sum_of_salary"]

# OR

sal = (df.groupby("Department", as_index=False)
         .agg(Sum_of_salary=("Salary", "sum")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`method is little different from general dataframe methods , As groupby method doesnot give a DataFrame or Series in return directly meaning it allows us to split the dataframe into groups but only in an abstract sense.Nothing really get computed until a function is called on Groupby object.

Also remember a groupby function follows (split-apply-combine): Split the dataframe-apply the function-combine the result.
Also Groupby objects are returned by groupby calls
I think rather than using head() function directly
Use: `DataFrameGroupBy.head([n])`:Return first n rows of each group.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).